# Propel and symfony : Join Table doesn't work

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

Firstly I explain  my issue :

I have two tables Job and JobCategory :

```
job:
   -------------------------------------------------
   | id   | category_job_id | job_name  | keywords  |
   -------------------------------------------------

JobCategory: 
  -------------------------
  | id   | categoty_name  |
  -------------------------
```

tho two tables is related by foreign key "category_job_id".

In this application I'm using Propel ORM. I hoped to make search using three fields keywords, job_name and category_name.

The first field is keywords is "input" who I can write keywords, the second field is Category_name is a "select", list of category. The third field is Job_name and is a "select", list of Job name, and if is not empty the keywords fields will be ignored.

I make function of search like this, but it doesn't work for me:

```
  public function searchFilter($job,$category,$keyword)
   {

$order = isset($this->order) ? $this->order : Criteria::ASC;

$job = '%' .$job. '%';
$category = '%' .$category. '%';

$c = new Criteria();

$c->addJoin(JobPeer::CATEGORY_JOB_ID, JobCategoryPeer::ID);
if((null !== $category) AND ($category !== ""))
{
 $c->addOr(JobCategoryPeer::CATEGORY_NAME,$category, Criteria::LIKE);    
}
if((null !== $job) AND ($job !== ""))
{
 $c->addOr(JobPeer::JOB_NAME,$job, Criteria::LIKE);   
}

$query = JobQuery::create(null, $c)
        ->joinWith('Job.JobCategory')
        ->orderByDateOfJob($order);

  if((null !== $keyword) AND ($keyword !== "")){
    $keyword = '%' .$keyword. '%';
    $query->filterByKeywords($keyword, Criteria::LIKE);
  }      

$results = $query->find();


return $results;

}
```

But the search is all cases is wrong!

Comment: I don't think it is the solution to your question, but there's a few mistakes in your post. Your table is likely to be `job_category`, not `JobCategory` - the latter is your corresponding model class. I should think `categoty_name` should be `category_name` too.

Comment: Have a look at the Propel docs btw: there's a `toString` method (or similar) you can apply to `$query`, which will give you the SQL it has generated. This is invaluable for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will work. If not, you can get the generated SQL before issuing the `find()` (see below) so that you (and we) can see what the output might be.

```
public function searchFilter($job,$category,$keyword)
{

  $order = isset($this->order) ? $this->order : Criteria::ASC;

  $query = JobQuery::create()->joinWith('JobCategory');
  $conditions = array();

  if((null !== $category) AND ($category !== ""))
  {
    $query->condition('catName', "JobCategory.CategoryName LIKE ?", "%$category%");
    $conditions[] = 'catName';
  }
  if((null !== $job) AND ($job !== ""))
  {
    $query->condition('jobName', "Job.JobName LIKE ?", "%$job%");
    $conditions[] = 'jobName';
  }
  if (sizeOf($conditions) > 1)
  {
     // join your conditions with an "or" if there are multiple
    $query->combine($conditions, Criteria::LOGICAL_OR, 'allConditions');
    // redefine this so we have the combined conditions
    $conditions = array('allConditions');
  }

  // add all conditions to query (might only be 1)
  $query->where($conditions);

  if((null !== $keyword) AND ($keyword !== ""))
  {
    $query->filterByKeywords("%$keyword%", Criteria::LIKE);
  }

  $query->orderByDateOfJob($order);
  $sql = $query->toString(); // log this value so we can see the SQL if there is a problem
  return $query->find();
}
```

Comment: Yea after some changes it's works very fine thanks a lot,but I have another stupid issue if you can help us...

Comment: here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155029/validation-form-in-symfony-1-4

Comment: If you don't have time, no problem!Tnks.

Comment: I took a look, but Symfony isn't really y area. I work with basic Propel. I'll take a better look tomorrow to see if I can help though.