# Validation form in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I create a search form in my project but the validation seems not to be working :

Filtersearchform :

```
class FilterSearchForm extends sfForm
 {
  public function configure()
    {

$def_volume = array(-1=>"Please select a volume");
$def_issue = array(-1=>"Please select issue");

$volumes = array_merge($def_volume,IssuePeer::getAllVolumesForListChoices());
$issues = array_merge($def_issue,IssuePeer::getAllIssuesForListChoices());


//******************************** WIDGET **************************************//
   $this->setWidgets(array(
  'keyword'    => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
  'volume' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $volumes)),
  'issue' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $issues)),
));

           //*****************************************  VALIDATORS           
          **********************************//
   $this->setValidators(array(
  'keyword'    => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
  'volume' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys(IssuePeer::getAllVolumesForListChoices()))),
  'issue' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys(IssuePeer::getAllIssuesForListChoices()))),
));


$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('filterSearch[%s]');
$this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);

}
```

}

in search action :

```
$this->form = new FilterSearchForm();
```

in search template :

```
            <form id="form_content" method="post" action="<?php echo url_for('@ResultSearch')  ?>">
                <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(); ?>

            <?php if($form->hasGlobalErrors()): ?>
            <ul class="error_list">
                <?php foreach($form->getGlobalErrors() as $name => $error): ?>
                <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
           <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="search_word" >

                        <?php echo $form['keyword']->render();?>
                <?php echo $form['keyword']->renderError() ?>
                </div>
                    <div class="select-wrapper" data-icon="&#710;">

                   <?php echo $form['volume']->render();?>
                   <?php echo $form['volume']->renderError() ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="select-wrapper" data-icon="&#710;" >
                                    <?php echo $form['issue']->render();?>
                <?php echo $form['issue']->renderError() ?>

                    </div>
                <div class="search_button">
                <button class="msg_submit_btn" id="fpost" type="submit"></button>
                </div>
        </form>
```

in Result search action :

```
 if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
  $this->form = new FilterSearchForm();
  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('filterSearch'));
  if ($this->form->isValid())
  {

      $values = $this->form->getValues();

   $keyword = trim($values['keyword']);
   $volume = trim($values['volume']);
   $issue = trim($values['issue']);

   $search= new Issue();

  $object = $search->searchFilter($issue, $volume, $keyword);

      $this->results= $object;   

  }
}
```

and Finally in ResultSearch Template :

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
.....
```

So for example in my search tempalte when I keep the keyword field empty in form and i click submit, that redirect me to Result search without showing the "error validation" ==> "keyword required".

hen I put var_dump i remark that the code also stop here `if ($this->form->isValid())` in Resultsearch action.

Any Idea?

Edit :

I remark that when I use just one page in the code above "search template",that mean the post method redirect in the same page `<form id="form_content" method="post" action="">`, so the validation of the form works fine,but not that what I wish,I hope to redirect after submitting and pass the data of search to another page in the code above is "Resultsearch" template.

Comment: Do you in fact display the potential form error in the result page? Anyway it's not the best workflow in my opinion. When your form has errors you show the result page without any results, and the user cannot correct the errors. What I would do is to submit the form to the same action where you display it and if the form is valid then redirect to the results page, otherwise show the form again together with info about errors.

Comment: No if you see the code above,I have the form in "SearchSuccess.php" so the validation it make in the same page but the information of search will be send to "ResultSearchSuccess.php" by default using post method?